# Pyparsing : issues with setResultsName

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm parsing multiple choice questions with multiple answers that look like this :

```
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(u""" \t""")
in_ = """1) first stem.
= option one one key
= option one two key
- option one three distractor
= option one four key
2) second stem ?
- option two one distractor
- option two two distractor
= option one three key
3) third stem.
- option three one key
= option three two distractor
"""
```

The equal sign represents a correct answer, the dash a distractor.

My grammar looks like this :

```
newline = Suppress(u"\n")
end_number = Suppress(oneOf(u') / ('))
end_stem = Suppress(oneOf(u"? .")) + newline
end_phrase = Optional(u'.').suppress() + newline
phrase = OneOrMore(Word(alphas)) + end_phrase
prefix = Word(u"-", max=1)('distractor') ^ Word(u"=", max=1)('key')
stem = Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphas))) + end_stem
number = Word(nums) + end_number
question = number + stem('stem') +
    Group(OneOrMore(Group(prefix('prefix') + phrase('phrase'))))('options')
```

And when I'm parsing the results:

```
for match, start, end in question.scanString(in_):
    for o in match.options:
        try:
            print('key', o.prefix.key)
        except:
            print('distractor', o.prefix.distractor)
```

I get :

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'distractor'
```

I'm pretty sure the result names are chainable. If so, what am I doing wrong ? I can easily work around this but it's unsatisfactory not knowing what I did wrong and what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `o` is actually the prefix -- when you call `o.prefix`, you're actually going one level deeper then you need to, and are retrieving the string the prefix maps to, not the ParseResults object.

You can see this by modifying the code so that it prints out the parse tree:

```
for match, start, end in question.scanString(in_):
    for o in match.options:
        print o.asXML()
        try:
            print('key', o.prefix.key)
        except:
            print('distractor', o.prefix.distractor)
```

The code will then print out:

```
<prefix>
  <key>=</key>
  <phrase>option</phrase>
  <ITEM>one</ITEM>
  <ITEM>one</ITEM>
  <ITEM>key</ITEM>
</prefix>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so07.py", line 37, in <module>
    print('distractor', o.prefix.distractor)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'distractor'
```

The problem then becomes clear -- if `o` is the prefix, then it doesn't make sense to do `o.prefix`. Rather, you need to simply call `o.key` or `o.distractor`.

Also, it appears that if you try and call `o.key` where no key exists, then pyparsing will return an empty string rather than throwing an exception.

So, your fixed code should look like this:

```
for match, start, end in question.scanString(in_):
    for o in match.options:
        if o.key != '':
            print('key', o.key)
        else:
            print('distractor', o.distractor)
```

Comment: Nice answer - I recommend using `dump()` instead of `asXML()`, since the later is a little buggy.